# Yii2: Editing data send to the Database

Tags: mongodb, encryption, yii2

I'm using Yii2 to insert test data into my MongoDB database. 
I'm fairly new to Yii as a whole and I was wondering how I can change the data before it gets put into the database (Encrypt it with AES256 in my case).

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your model:
The default implementation will trigger an EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT event when $insert is true, or an EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE event if $insert is false. When overriding this method, make sure you call the parent implementation like the following:

```html
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
        // ...custom code here...
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

[for more information](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html)

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to give you a good example without any code, but you probably have your values in a variable `$model`, with a set of attributes. You can assign the attributes with `$model->attribute = aes256($myVariable);` before you do a `$model->save()`.

I would recommend reading the docs, there's alot of good information there.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html

> $customer = new Customer();
>
> $customer->name = 'Qiang';
>
> $customer->save();